# Start of Week in Amazon Redshift (Sunday Start of the Week)

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to convert Week to start with Sunday (range 1-53, with a Sunday in this year)

Ex. DATE_PART(w,'2020-01-05') (Sunday) 
This should return 2 instead of 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which day of the week would you like to be the "first" day of a week? Would it be Monday?

Comment: same here... I want it to be the Sunday. Is his proposed function already right to get the sunday as start of the week?

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to obtain the Week Number where a week starts on **Monday instead of Sunday**:

- Subtract one day to the date being convert to the Week Number

So, use:

```sql
DATE_PART(w, date_field - INTERVAL '1 DAY')
```

This returns the Week Number of the 'previous day'.

Unfortunately, it won't work for the first day of the year, which will appear to be the last day of the previous year. Depending on how your organization treats the first/last weeks of the year, this might be okay.

If that is not satisfactory, then you could write your own **User-Defined Function (UDF)** and code it to return the values you desire.